# Comparison Warning vs NullreferenceException

Tags: c#, winforms

```
foreach (Control c in panPrev.Controls)
{
if (c.Tag == "move")
```

works well, but produce a warning: *Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'*

```
foreach (Control c in panPrev.Controls)
{
if (c.Tag.ToString() == "move")  // this produce NullReferenceException.
```

What to do?

Comment: Another options would be re-write the call as `"move".Equals(c.Tag)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't take the suggestion offerred by the warning.  Which would be:

```
if ((string)c.Tag == "move")
```

This will work fine in the event that `Tag` is null, whereas trying to invoke `.ToString` on a possibly `null` reference opens you up to the exception you got.

The reason you need to do this at all is because `.Tag` is declared as an `object`, and so using the `==` operator between an `object` and a `string` uses reference equality, whereas comparing a `string` to a `string` uses the overload of `==` defined in `string` which is implemented to compare the actual values.

Answer (score 1):

`Tag` is of the type `object`, that's why you get the warning. If you know it to be a string and it should *always* be a string then you should cast it (C style) as you will catch errors quickly if `Tag` is not a string (but should be).

Comment: What do you mean there's nothing to worry about if it's a string under the hood?   The `==` comparison will fail without the cast if the strings are different instances.

Comment: @KirkWoll: You're right because `Tag` is of the type `object`, I didn't consider that and wrote too quickly.  My mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`c.Tag` is an object, so object == string does a reference comparison.

Object can be null, of course, so calling `Tag.ToString()` can throw a null reference exception in that case.

You should do as the warning suggests, and cast `Tag` to string:

```
if ((string)c.Tag == "move")
```